# Session variable is empty after page reload

Tags: php, session-variables

I want to set session variable and use it around the code. But after page reload this variable is empty. I don't understand why and how to write correct code.

```php
<?
if (session_id() == "")
    session_start();

echo'<p>'." SESSION before IF ".$_SESSION['test_sess'].'</p>'.'<p>'." SESSION 1 ".$_SESSION['test_sess_1'].'</p>';

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    echo '<p>'." CODE ".$_GET['code'].'</p>';
    echo '<p>'." SESSION in IF ".$_SESSION['test_sess'].'</p>';
    $_SESSION['test_sess'] = 'test_val';
    echo '<p>'." SESSION in the end IF ".$_SESSION['test_sess'].'</p>';
}

$_SESSION['test_sess_1'] = $_SESSION['test_sess'];
?>
```

I expect that after reloading page there will be 4 outputs with non-empty variables.

In the initial page I see:

SESSION before IF
SESSION 1
CODE 12345
SESSION in IF
SESSION in the end IF test_val

And after reload I expect to see:

SESSION before IF test_val
SESSION 1 test_val
CODE 12345
SESSION in IF test_val
SESSION in the end IF test_val

Comment: What is the current output of the _initial_ page load?

Comment: Because on second reload the `session_id() == "")` therefore the session is not started when you reload, remove `session_start()` within the condition and put on top everything will work

Comment: @PatrickQ, in the initial there are 
"SESSION before IF

SESSION 1

CODE 12345

SESSION in IF

SESSION in the end IF test_val"

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, there is no difference. Both variants (with session_id() == "" and without it) don't work.

Comment: Just put session start on top then lose the condition it should and will work as long as the if Get is true

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, this code is all my file. I put session_start() on the top just after <?. I need to set session variable in the condition and then use it in that file and in the other files. This file is about authorisation and in session variable I want to save access token.

Comment: I've copied your code. Opened `test.php?code=12345`. Then reloaded. And I see exactly what you're expecting